# awk and system and print and append to csv file

Tags: bash, awk, osx, csv

I am trying to append a column to a csv file that has 13 columns.
I am executing the following command:

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } {gsub(/"/, "", $1);$14=system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \""$1"\" \"+%s\"");print}' mycsv.csv > test
```

The result is that at the end of 13 field the following is appended `^M,1` (or `^M,0` and the new column's value which is supposed to be the $14 is added to a second line.
So the csv breaks.
What is the problem here?

Example input:

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"
```

Expected output:

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now", 1485771295
```

**UPDATE:**
This:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN{ OFS="," } {gsub(/"/, "", $1);system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \""$1"\" \"+%s\"")|getline $14; print}' mycsv.csv > test
```

Does not have the 0 or 1 from the exit status of `system` but has the `^M` and new line characted and hence the $14 is printed in a new line

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$ cat mycsv.csv 
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"  
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"  
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"
```

Doing:

```
$ awk -F"," '{printf; printf ","; gsub(/"/, "", $1);system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \""$1"\" \"+%s\"")}' mycsv.csv > test  
Failed conversion of ``1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM'' using format ``%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p''  
date: illegal time format  
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...   
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

And result file:
When I do cat I see:

```
$ cat test
,1485771295 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"  
,148577129511:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"
```

When I open with vim I see a `^M` after `"Now"`

**UPDATE 3:**
Something strange, I can't print the full line. The following gives garbage:

```
$awk -F',' '{ printf $0 }' mycsv.csv   
","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now""
```

But this works (but I don't want the new line that print adds):

```
$ awk -F',' '{ print $0; }' mycsv.csv   
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"  
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"  
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `awk(1)` we read that

```
   system(cmd)
          executes cmd and returns its exit status
```

So the 0 is the exit status returned by the result of the system command (a normal exit). In this case you probably need to print the existing columns, a comma, then do the date so the standard out of that gets put in the right place, as a simplified example shows:

```
(echo a,b,c; echo e,f,g) \
| awk -F, '{printf "%s", $0;printf ",";system("echo more")}'
```

Appending a new column with input from the first column is not very different: print the data, append a comma, alter `$1` for the subsequent system, make the system call.

```
$ cat input 
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M"
$ awk -F, '{printf "%s", $0;printf ",";gsub(/"/, "", $1);system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \""$1"\" \"+%s\"")}' input
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM","I","M",1485774895
```

Comment: In my case I need to modify the first field of the csv row with system. I am not sure how I can reformat it based on your example

Comment: Reforming and appending are two very different things. Do you have sample input and expected output?

Comment: I mean you are doing `system("echo more")`. I am doing `system(date(...$1))`

Comment: I tried this and does not work: `for i in $(cat mycsv.csv); do echo $i | awk -F "," '{printf; printf ","; gsub(/"/, "", $1);system("date -jf \"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p\" \""$1"\" \"+%s\"");}';done`

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Do you have sample input and expected output?

Comment: Please see update

Comment: I keep getting a `^M` before the timestamp. What is that character?

Comment: Please see new update in OP

Comment: This is the problem. This `$ awk -F "," '{printf}' mycsv.csv` results in garbage i.e. `","M","k6.0.1","E","jim","JimK","JIM","jim@gmail.com","A","6.0.12","A","Now""`

Comment: This adds the new line character: `awk -F "," '{print; printf ","}' mycsv.csv`